# Calculating precision and recall does not work. len() error

Tags: python

I have the following two simple functions. I created two list with sample error to test the functions but one of them is not working properly. I think the problem has to do with `len()`

```
import numpy as np

def apk(actual, predicted, k=10):
    """
    Computes the average precision at k.
    This function computes the average prescision at k between two lists of
    items.
    Parameters
    ----------
    actual : list
             A list of elements that are to be predicted (order doesn't matter)
    predicted : list
                A list of predicted elements (order does matter)
    k : int, optional
        The maximum number of predicted elements
    Returns
    -------
    score : double
            The average precision at k over the input lists
    """
    if len(predicted)>k:
        predicted = predicted[:k]

    score = 0.0
    num_hits = 0.0

    for i,p in enumerate(predicted):
        if p in actual and p not in predicted[:i]:
            num_hits += 1.0
            score += num_hits / (i+1.0)

    if not actual:
        return 0.0

    return score / min(len(actual), k)

def mapk(actual, predicted, k=10):
    """
    Computes the mean average precision at k.
    This function computes the mean average prescision at k between two lists
    of lists of items.
    Parameters
    ----------
    actual : list
             A list of lists of elements that are to be predicted 
             (order doesn't matter in the lists)
    predicted : list
                A list of lists of predicted elements
                (order matters in the lists)
    k : int, optional
        The maximum number of predicted elements
    Returns
    -------
    score : double
            The mean average precision at k over the input lists
    """
    return np.mean([apk(a,p,k) for a,p in zip(actual, predicted)])
```

When I call both of them:

```
actual = [6,9,5,3]
predicted = [6,9,5,0]
predicted.sort(reverse=True)
print("\nAP@K",apk(actual, predicted,k=4))
print("\nMAP@K",mapk(actual, predicted,k=4))
```

I get this error on the second one:

```
<ipython-input-11-2db5b0a21be1> in apk(actual, predicted, k)
      3 def apk(actual, predicted, k=4):
      4 
----> 5     if len(predicted)>k:
      6         predicted = predicted[:k]
      7 #     print("Real",actual)
```

AP@K 0.75

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: The call to `apk` in `mapk` is given integers *from* `actual` and `predicted`, not the lists `actual` and `predicted` itself.

Comment: @chepner No. I think it has to do with sending a list of lists.

Comment: You don't have any lists of lists. What you *do* have is the sequence of `(int, int)` tuples produced by `zip`, and each element of those tuples is based to `apk` where it expects a list.

Comment: Either your definition of `mapk` is incorrect, or you are passing the wrong arguments to `mapk`.

Comment: @chepner No. It clearly says that you should pass a list of lists. And actually it works when doing so. I will update the op. But your approach, so far, is not accurate enough.

Comment: OK, then you should *do* that. Right now you are just passing lists of `int`s. Neither `actual` nor `predicted` is a list of lists.

Comment: In your definition it's stated that you should pass list of lists, meanwhile you are passing just a list.

Answer (score 1):

your listcomp in the mapk `[apk(a,p,k) for a,p in zip(actual, predicted)]` is basically doing:

`apk(6,9,4)`

If you want to pass list of lists in mapk, you need to modify your `predicted, actual` to contain list of lists. For example, try it with:

```
actual = [[6,9,5,3],[2,3,4,5],[5,6,2,3]]
predicted = [[9,6,5,0], [2,6,1,3], [3,5,6,2]]
```

If this is what you wanted, you will probably have to change your apk function, since len(predicted) will give you the number of lists in the modified `predicted` list of lists, instead of giving you the # of items in a nested list.